# HTTP Basic Auth for some (not all) controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

Using Rails 3.2.

I have half a dozen controllers, and want to protect **some** (but not all) of them with `http_basic_authenticate_with`.

I don't want to manually add `http_basic_authenticate_with` to each controller (I could add another controller in the future and forget to protect it!). It seems the answer is to put it in `application_controller.rb` with an `:except` arg which would list the controllers that should *not* be protected. The problem is, the :except clause wants method names rather than external controller module names, e.g.:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => 'xxx', :password => 'yyy', :except => :foo, :bar
```

So then I thought "Wait, since I already have the protected controllers grouped in `routes.rb`, let's put it there." So I tried this in my routes:

```
  scope "/billing" do
    http_basic_authenticate_with :name ...
    resources :foo, :bar ...
  end
```

But now I get

```
undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with'
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: One option is to have a `class ProtectedController < ApplicationController`, put `http_basic_authenticate` there and inherit protected controllers from it.

Comment: If you happen to be using devise for authentication, you can enable basic auth with devise instead of rails - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication - might not be relevant in your case?

Comment: Sergio, that would put me back in the same place I'm trying to avoid - I'd have to manually add each new controller I want protected. If I was willing to do that, I could have simply put the http_base_authenticate line into each controller.

Comment: @house9 I had not heard of Devise, thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 50):

Do it the way Rails does it.

```
# rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb

def http_basic_authenticate_with(options = {})
  before_action(options.except(:name, :password, :realm)) do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic(options[:realm] || "Application") do |name, password|
      name == options[:name] && password == options[:password]
    end
  end
end
```

All that `http_basic_authenticate_with` does is add a `before_action`. You can just as easily do the same  yourself:

```
# application_controller.rb

before_action :http_basic_authenticate

def http_basic_authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |name, password|
    name == 'xxx' && password == 'yyy'
  end
end
```

which means you can use `skip_before_action` in controllers where this behavior isn't desired:

```
# unprotected_controller.rb

skip_before_action :http_basic_authenticate
```

Comment: Thank @SamBlake. This should be the accepted answer.