# Rails Way to handle single admin on site with no user model/login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm wondering what the most straightforward or canonical Rails way of handling this situation might be. I have a simple blog site. There is no user login feature--users are just visitors to the site who can read content. I want to be able to edit the content through an admin login. I'll be the only admin.

It seems like overkill to create a User model just to assign myself the role of admin. I watched a few of Ryan Bates' [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/20-restricting-access) about this issue, but I worried that his solution might be insecure (storing passwords as plain text within the App. Controller). The only other solution I can think of doesn't seem very satisfactory/secure either: just creating an admin model and seeding the database with a single admin user.

I'd appreciate any feedback on the best way to proceed as well as potential pros and cons for different approaches. Definitely feeling stuck on how to create a single admin with a secure/hashed password stored in the DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth method:

if it's suits your requirements, you may use the Ryan approach, however HTTP basic auth might also be used here [HTTP Basic Auth for some (not all) controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790832/http-basic-auth-for-some-not-all-controllers) - you do not need any form views then.

Admin username and password can be stored in a various methods:

- within a file, just like you specify your database connection config; then you only need to load pass from file;
- straight in controller, I don't see any vulnerability here, unless your code repository is public;
- declaring an ENV variable with password but this is the most unsecure method among the others.

For any method above, it would be good practice to use some encryption.

Any other solution need database and at least one model declared. Besides that, simple user model with sha1(password) will not make your app more secure. Finer encryption needs at least password salt and you can implement it quite straightforward, i.e. copy+paste from some popular authentication gem.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having the pass in a controller b/c I will be using a public repo, so I like the idea of storing the password in a file that I keep in my .gitignore (either secrets.yml or database.yml?). I'm not sure if I'd be able to access the password in the app. Is storing the pass this way an option? How can I check against this when authenticating over a server?

Comment: Of course you can store the file name in .gitignore. The name of file can be anything. You do not need to store password secrets.yml or database.yml (and that actually should be avoided since purpose of these files is quite different). Simply create a file, i.e. config/access.yml and put there encrypted password. Within your app, just read the file and read the enrypted password and then compare with password provided by user. If you're deploying via `Capistrano`, for sure you can even integrate it and re-generate password with each deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid dedicating an entire model (which I don't think is the worst idea in history), you could still do some manual encryption, and save that to your controller instead. For instance the following view code will give you some encrypted constants:

```
<% salt = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Make some unique salt using "+ Time.now.to_s) %>
<% password = "mypassword1" %>
<% encrypted_data = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password + " with some " + salt) %>

Salt: <%= salt %>
<br />
Encrypted: <%= encrypted_data %>
<br />
```

Which will render something like:

```
Salt: f00ab3d3c576c97a43f87b556f0570dc088b2e81
Encrypted: cc4fe9875c67ac9d6505af1f627ba446bed78647
```

Storing those constants to your controller, or to a locale file, is a bit safer than storing the actual password in your controller – and you can still authenticate by checking if:

```
"cc4fe9875c67ac9d6505af1f627ba446bed78647" == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass_from_form + " with some " + "f00ab3d3c576c97a43f87b556f0570dc088b2e81")
```

or better yet (using locales):

```
I18n.t('credentials.encrypted_password') == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass_from_form + " with some " + I18n.t('credentials.salt'))
```